# joining on count and rank the result t sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Here's my Count_query:

```
Declare @yes_count decimal;
Declare @no_count decimal;

set @yes_count=(Select count(*) from Master_Data where Received_Data='Yes');
set @no_count=(Select count(*) from Master_Data where Received_Data='No');
select @yes_count As Yes_Count,@no_count as No_Count,(@yes_count/(@yes_count+@no_count)) As Submission_Count
```

I am having trouble making joins on these two queries

This is the rest of the query:

```
Select Distinct D.Member_Id,d.Name,d.Region_Name, D.Domain,e.Goal_Abbreviation, 
 e.Received_Data, case when Received_Data = 'Service Not Provided'  then null 
 when Received_Data = 'No' then null   else e.Improvement end  as 
  Percent_Improvement , case when Received_Data = 'Service Not Provided'  then null 
  when Received_Data = 'No' then null else e.Met_40_20 end as Met_40_20 
   FROM (
select  distinct member_Domains.*,
        (case when NoData.Member_Id is null then 'Participating' else ' ' end) as Participating
        from
        (
        select distinct members.Member_Id, members.Name, Members.Region_Name, 
        case when Domains.Goal_Abbreviation = 'EED Reduction' then 'EED' 
        When Domains.Goal_Abbreviation = 'Pressure Ulcers' then 'PRU' 
          when Domains.Goal_Abbreviation = 'Readmissions' then 'READ' else Domains.Goal_Abbreviation end as Domain from 
        (select g.* from    Program_Structure as ps inner join Goal as g on ps.Goal_Id = g.Goal_Id 
        and ps.Parent_Goal_ID = 0) as Domains
        cross join
        (select distinct hc.Member_ID, hc.Name,hc.Region_Name from zsheet as z 
        inner join Hospital_Customers$ as hc on z.CCN = hc.Mcare_Id) as Members
        ) as member_Domains
        left outer join Z_Values_Hospitals as NoData on member_Domains.member_ID = NoData.Member_Id 
        and Member_Domains.Domain = noData.ReportName) D

Left Outer JOIN

(SELECT B.Member_ID, B.Goal_Abbreviation, B.minRate, C.maxRate, B.BLine, C.Curr_Quarter, B.S_Domain,
(CASE WHEN B.Member_ID IN
                      (SELECT member_id
                       FROM      Null_Report
                       WHERE   ReportName = B.S_Domain) THEN 'Service Not Provided' WHEN Curr_Quarter = 240 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END) AS Received_Data, 

                       ROUND((CASE WHEN minRate = 0 AND maxRate = 0 THEN 0 WHEN minRate = 0 AND maxRate > 0 THEN 1 ELSE (((maxRate - minRate) / minRate) * 100) END), .2) AS Improvement, 
                  (CASE WHEN ((CASE WHEN minRate = 0 AND maxRate = 0 THEN 0 WHEN minRate = 0 AND maxRate > 0 THEN 1 ELSE (maxRate - minRate) / minRate END)) <= - 0.4 OR
                  maxRate = 0 THEN 'Yes' WHEN ((CASE WHEN minRate = 0 AND maxRate = 0 THEN 0 WHEN minRate = 0 AND maxRate > 0 THEN 1 ELSE (maxRate - minRate) / minRate END)) 
                  <= - 0.2 OR maxRate = 0 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END) AS Met_40_20
FROM     (SELECT tab.Member_ID, tab.Measure_Value AS minRate, tab.Goal_Abbreviation, A.BLine, tab.S_Domain 
                  FROM      Measure_Table_Description AS tab INNER JOIN
                                        (SELECT DISTINCT 
                                                           Member_ID AS new_memid, Goal_Abbreviation AS new_measure, MIN(Reporting_Period_ID) AS BLine, MAX(Reporting_Period_ID) 
                                                           AS Curr_Quarter
                                         FROM      Measure_Table_Description
                                         WHERE   (Member_ID > 1) AND (Measure_Value IS NOT NULL) AND (Measure_ID LIKE '%O%')
                                         GROUP BY Goal_Abbreviation, Member_ID) AS A ON tab.Member_ID = A.new_memid AND tab.Reporting_Period_ID = A.BLine AND 
                                    tab.Goal_Abbreviation = A.new_measure) AS B FULL OUTER JOIN
                      (SELECT tab.Member_ID, tab.Measure_Value AS maxRate, tab.Goal_Abbreviation, A_1.Curr_Quarter
                       FROM      Measure_Table_Description AS tab INNER JOIN
                                             (SELECT DISTINCT 
                                                                Member_ID AS new_memid, Goal_Abbreviation AS new_measure,
                                                                 MIN(Reporting_Period_ID) AS BLine, MAX(Reporting_Period_ID) 
                                                                AS Curr_Quarter
                                              FROM      Measure_Table_Description AS Measure_Table_Description_1
                                              WHERE   (Member_ID >1) AND (Measure_Value IS NOT NULL) AND (Measure_ID LIKE '%O%')
                                              GROUP BY Goal_Abbreviation, Member_ID) AS A_1 ON tab.Member_ID = A_1.new_memid
                                               AND tab.Reporting_Period_ID = A_1.Curr_Quarter AND 
                                         tab.Goal_Abbreviation = A_1.new_measure) AS C ON B.Member_ID = C.Member_ID 




 WHERE  (B.Goal_Abbreviation = C.Goal_Abbreviation) )  E ON D.Member_Id = E.Member_ID AND d.Domain = E.S_Domain 

ORDER BY D.Domain,D.Member_ID
```

How do I get a count of the 'yes'/ (count(yes)+count(no)) for each member_ID as column1 and also display  the rank of each member_ID against all the member_IDs in the result as column2. I have come up with a query that generates the count for the entire table, but how do I restrict it each Member_ID.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't taken the time to digest your provided query, but if abstracted to the concept of having an aggregate over a range of data repeated on each row, you should look at using windowing functions. There are other methods, such as using a CTE to do your aggregation and then JOINing back to your detailed data. That might work better for more complex calculations, but the window functions are arguably the more elegant option.

```
DECLARE @MasterData AS TABLE 
(
    MemberID varchar(50),
    MemberAnswer int 
);
INSERT INTO @MasterData (MemberID, MemberAnswer) VALUES ('Jim', 1);
INSERT INTO @MasterData (MemberID, MemberAnswer) VALUES ('Jim', 0);
INSERT INTO @MasterData (MemberID, MemberAnswer) VALUES ('Jim', 1);
INSERT INTO @MasterData (MemberID, MemberAnswer) VALUES ('Jim', 1);
INSERT INTO @MasterData (MemberID, MemberAnswer) VALUES ('Jane', 1);
INSERT INTO @MasterData (MemberID, MemberAnswer) VALUES ('Jane', 0);
INSERT INTO @MasterData (MemberID, MemberAnswer) VALUES ('Jane', 1);

-- Method 1, using windowing functions (preferred for performance and syntactical compactness)
SELECT
    MemberID,
    MemberAnswer,
    CONVERT(numeric(19,4),SUM(MemberAnswer) OVER (PARTITION BY MemberID)) / CONVERT(numeric(19,4),COUNT(MemberAnswer) OVER (PARTITION BY MemberID)) AS PercentYes
FROM        @MasterData;

-- Method 2, using a CTE

WITH MemberSummary AS
(
    SELECT
        MemberID,
        SUM(MemberAnswer) AS MemberYes,
        COUNT(MemberAnswer) AS MemberTotal
    FROM        @MasterData
    GROUP BY    MemberID
)
SELECT
    md.MemberID,
    md.MemberAnswer,
    CONVERT(numeric(19,4),MemberYes) / CONVERT(numeric(19,4),MemberTotal) AS PercentYes
FROM        @MasterData md
JOIN        MemberSummary ms
ON          md.MemberID = ms.MemberID;
```

Answer (score 0):

First thought is: your query is much, much too complicated. I have spent about 10 minutes now trying to make sense of it and haven't gotten anywhere, so it's obviously going to pose a long-term maintenance challenge to those within your organization going forward as well. I would really recommend you try to find some way of simplifying it.

That said, here is a simplified, general example of how to query on a calculated value and rank the results:

```
CREATE TABLE member (member_id INT PRIMARY KEY);

CREATE TABLE master_data (
  transaction_id INT PRIMARY KEY, 
  member_id INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES member(member_id),
  received_data BIT
);

-- INSERT data here

; WITH member_data_counts AS (
  SELECT 
    m.member_id, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM master_data d WHERE d.member_id = m.member_id AND d.received_data = 1) num_yes, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM master_data d WHERE d.member_id = m.member_id AND d.received_data = 0) num_no
  FROM member m
), member_data_calc AS (
  SELECT 
    *, 
    CASE 
      WHEN (num_yes + num_no) = 0 THEN NULL  -- avoid division-by-zero error
      ELSE num_yes / (num_yes + num_no)
    END pct_yes
  FROM member_data_counts 
), member_data_rank AS (
  SELECT *, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY pct_yes DESC) AS RankValue
  FROM member_data_calc
) 
SELECT * 
FROM member_data_rank
ORDER BY RankValue ASC;
```